# Reducer is not accumulating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to use reducer to accumulate an amount that comes from an Api

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  items:[],
}

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'basket',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.items = [...state.items, action.payload]
    },
    removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.items.findIndex(item => item.title === action.payload.title);

      let newBasket = [...state.items];

      if (index >= 0) {
        newBasket.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        console.log(`Can't remove product (id: ${action.payload.id} as its not in basket!)`)
      }

      state.items = newBasket;
    }
  },
})

export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket } = basketSlice.actions

export const selectBasketItems = state => state.basket.items;

export const selectBasketItemsWithId = (state, title) => state.basket.items.filter((item) => item.title === title);

// here's is the function
export const selectBasketTotal = (state) => state.basket.items.reduce((total, item) => total += item.price, 0)

export default basketSlice.reducer
```

And I'm using here

```js
const BasketIcon = () => {
  const items = useSelector(selectBasketItems);
  const basketTotal = useSelector(selectBasketTotal);

  return (
    { basketTotal }
  )
}
```

[image: Here's the result]

I did try to use the reduce function directly in the component

```js
const BasketIcon = ({ price }) => {
  const items = useSelector(selectBasketItems);
    
    const basketTotal = items.reduce((total, item) => total += item.price, 0)
}
```

Also put `console.log` in every function, but didn't found where is the problem.

Comment: what is `basketSlice.actions` ? what is `basketSlice.reducer`? neither of these things are defined anywhere so exporting them exports nothing

Comment: also, `.reduce((total, item) => total += item.price, 0)` you'd do `.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)` instead, no?

Comment: Is defining ```here export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket } = basketSlice.actions```
and ```basketSlice.reducer``` is the entire slice, no?

Comment: if your item.price is a string, it's concatenating strings and not numbers. use Number.parseFloat() or Number.parseInt() based on your use case

Comment: I tried ```.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)``` but then the amount doesn't shows up in the button

Comment: Thank you @Derek it works now. Is there anyway to give a reward? I'm new here